# The Fibonacci sequence using threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fibonacci

I wrote a program in C to generate a Fibonacci sequence with n numbers where each  Fibonacci number created by a separate thread, the parent thread outputs whole produced Fibonacci sequence yet I got wrong sequence for n>2 it some how rewrite the value of the last element  in the Fibonacci sequence array to 0 if n>2 .How i can fix it? please find the code below.

```
/*============================================================================
   Description :The Fibonacci sequence
  ============================================================================ */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;                          // size of fibonacci sequence.
int *fibseq;                    // arry holds the value of each fibonacci term.
int i;                          // counter for the threads.

void *runn(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("format is:./a.out <intgervalue>\n");
        return -1;
    }                           // valdiate num of args.

    if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
    {
        printf("%d must be>=0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }                           // valdiate value of arg1.

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    fibseq = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(n * sizeof(pthread_t));
    pthread_attr_t attr;        // set of thread attribute

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, runn, NULL);
    }                           // End of creating threads.

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
    }                           // End of wating the threads to exit.

    // printing fibseq.
    printf("The Fibonacci sequence.:");
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        printf("%d,", fibseq[k]);
    }                           // End of printing fibseq.
    return 0;
}                               // End of main.

void *runn(void *arg)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        fibseq[i] = 0;
        pthread_exit(0);
    }                           // first fib term

    if (i == 1)
    {
        fibseq[i] = 1;
        pthread_exit(0);
    }                           // seconed fib term
    else
    {
        fibseq[0] = 0;
        fibseq[1] = 1;

        int p, pp, fibp, fibpp;

        p = (i - 1);
        pp = (i - 2);
        fibp = fibseq[p];
        // printf("fibseq[%d]%d\n",p,fibp);
        fibpp = fibseq[pp];
        // printf("fibseq[%d]%d\n",pp,fibpp);
        fibseq[i] = fibseq[i - 1] + fibseq[i - 2];
        // printf("fibseq[%d]%d,\n",i,fibseq[i]);
        pthread_exit(0);        // thread exit.
    }                           // End of else
}                               // End of run.
```

Comment: Since each value depends on the previous ones, why do you want to do it with threads? It will only lead to problems as you've noticed. Nothing says that value n would be determined before n+1, so values are garbage.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems quite ill-suited to parallelization. You would have to sequence the threads one after the other anyway.

Comment: The aim is to practice how threads together can produce the sequence and i used  pthread_join to synchronize the threads but still can not get the correct output

Answer (score 1):

I see that this post is from December of 2015, however the answer to your problem is quite simple. The reason is because you are using two separate for loops to create and join your threads. What this is doing is causing i < n threads to create and run through your *runn function at the same time. Meaning the threads are not waiting for the array to be updated.

They should be in a single for loop, that way the thread_join statement regulates each thread during each loop cycle. As I did below.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, runn, NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Now your threads are going through your *runn function one at a time. Thus fixing your issue.

On a side note you seem to have some unnecessary code towards the bottom of your *runn function this isn't necessary and is just redoing the work you have already done.

```
 fibseq[0] = 0; //this is unnecessary, because from your first threads fibseq[0] should 
                //already equal 0
 fibseq[1] = 1; //same for here this value should be equal to 1 already
```

Also, this is unnecessary. Although if I understand it correctly, this was used for debugging purposes right?

```
int p, pp, fibp, fibpp;

p = (i - 1);
pp = (i - 2);
fibp = fibseq[p];
// printf("fibseq[%d]%d\n",p,fibp);
fibpp = fibseq[pp];
// printf("fibseq[%d]%d\n",pp,fibpp);
```

The only relevant code needed for the else statement is here

```
fibseq[i] = fibseq[i - 1] + fibseq[i - 2];
pthread_exit(0);        // thread exit.
```

I hope this helps answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonnaci sequence is ill-suited to a parallelized solution.  There's actually a [closed-form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) that's not too difficult to compute and almost certainly faster than even a thread-based solution:

```
Fn = (φn - ψn) / √5
```

where `φ = (1 + √5) / 2` and `ψ = (1 - √5) / 2`.

<sup>**Edit** - on my system, the closed form diverges for `n` > 71 due to accumulated rounding errors; using an arbitrary-precision library would help with that.</sup>

If you're determined to make this work, however, you have to keep the following in mind:

1. You cannot compute `fibseq[i]` unless `fibseq[i-1]` and `fibseq[i-2]` have already been computed; you will need to use a [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) to pause execution of thread `i` until threads `i-1` and `i-2` have completed;
2. You have a *race condition* where `main` is updating the value of `i` while the threads are trying to use the value of `i` at the same time.  You could use a [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) to synchronize accesses of `i`, but honestly a better solution would be to pass the *value* of `i` as an argument to the thread (passing the address won't help; you'll have the same synchronization issue).

Comment: i tried to pass `i` to the thread function but i still have the same wrong output .Is there an other  way to use `pthread_join` to synchronize accesses of i because as you can see in the code i tried to use it but i cant see the problem in it. Thank you

Comment: @learn: there's still the issue that `fibseq[i]` cannot be computed until `fibseq[i-1]` and `fibseq[i-2]` have been computed; if array elements are computed out-of-order, then you won't get the correct output.  That's why this is such a *bad* fit for a parallel thread-based solution.  Threads 2 through `n` have to wait while threads 0 and 1 do their thing, then threads 3 through `n` have to wait for thread 2 to finish, then threads 4 through `n` have to wait for thread 3, etc.